# cocoa beginSheet: didEndSelector throwing an error

Tags: cocoa, nsapplication, cocoa-sheet

I'm loading a sheet into my main .xib, the sheet is a panel and I have no problem displaying the sheet or closing it but when I close it I am getting an error message:

```
2012-02-21 11:10:12.142 CollectionTest2[23277:10b] *** -
[AppController customSheetDidClose:returnCode:contextInfo:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x359c00
```

Here is my code:

```
/*Sheet Methods*/

- (void)showCustomSheet: (NSWindow *)window { 

    [NSApp beginSheet: panFilenameEditor modalForWindow: window modalDelegate: self didEndSelector: @selector(customSheetDidClose:returnCode:contextInfo:) contextInfo: nil];
}

- (IBAction)closeCustomSheet:(id)sender {

    [panFilenameEditor orderOut:self];
    [NSApp endSheet:panFilenameEditor];
}

- (void) customSheetDidClose   { 

    NSLog(@"sheet did close");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `showCustomSheet` method, you tell the sheet to call the selector `customSheetDidClose:returnCode:contextInfo:` on your app controller. But there is no such method.

There are two solutions:

- Either pass `@selector(customSheetDidClose)` in your call to `beginSheet:modalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:`.
- Or rename your `customSheetDidCloseMethod` to `- (void)customSheetDidClose:(NSWindow *)sheet returnCode:(NSInteger)returnCode contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo`.

Comment: @DD - thanks, I was just looking at the docs again and not understanding it but your explanation makes sense. App is working fine now.